# How do I return both "name" and "posts" using Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook api request for posts from a FB app. I thought I was following the correct syntax with my code, but when I try to pull "data.name" its coming up "undefined".

```
FB.api('/' + userName + '?fields=name,posts{message,created_time,full_picture,link,type,message_tags,description,from}', 
       { access_token : pageAccessToken }, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                var data = response.data[i];
                console.log(data);
                if (data.type !== "offer") { // types include: link, status, photo, video, offer
                   outputFBPost(data);   
                } 
            } 
        } else { console.log(response.error); }
    });
```

Comment: Log the response object to console, and check what it contains. Requesting user details via the user name is not possible any more, that was removed with API v2.0.

Comment: I tried loging the console for the response. It returns an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". So I tried returning just "/userName" (the same as me, in this case) and it was still undefined.

Comment: Of course it returns an error, because `response.data` does not exist ... that’s why I said you should log the `response` object to console; do that first thing in your callback function, before you try to loop over stuff o do anything else.

Comment: No, I tried logging just response not response.data

Comment: Did you do it first thing in the callback function? (That the error message is _not_ from console.log is clear, I hope.)

Comment: Yes, I did console.log(response) directly after the call to the API and before the first "if" statement.

Comment: Then you should get an output of the object, or at least undefined or something.